# Storing entire file content in a single String variable (Apache-Beam)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to store the entire File content (File is placed in GCS Bucket) in a single String variable. I know this is possible using Cloud Storage library and couldn't find any related example as reference.

Please provide me any working code-reference of this use-case.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920895/read-a-file-from-gcs-in-apache-beam/45946643#45946643

Comment: Tried the piece of code you suggested but getting this exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find registrar for gs
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal(FileSystems.java:447)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchNewResource(FileSystems.java:523)
 at com.bitwise.cloud.XMLReader.main(XMLReader.java:73)

Comment: I edited my answer to that question, try again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file from GCS in Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920895/read-a-file-from-gcs-in-apache-beam)

Comment: Tried and it worked perfectly !!! Thank you so much.