# What's the most idiomatic way to create a PCollection of N permutations of an input variable from file?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use Apache Beam to parallelize `N` trials of a simulation. This simulation is run on a matrix `V` sourced from a `.mat` MATLAB file. My first instinct (forgive me, I'm new to Apache Beam/Dataflow) was to extend `FileBasedSource`, but further investigation convinced me that this is not the case. Most explicitly, [Apache Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-custom-io/#creating-a-new-source) indicates, "You should create a new source if you’d like to use the advanced features that the Source API provides," and I don't need any of them—I just want to read a variable (or few)! I eventually stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946643, which is how I now intend to get `V` (passing the resultant file-like object from `FileSystems.open` to `scipy.io.loadmat`).

The next question is how create a `PCollection` of `N` permutations of `V`. The obvious solution is something like `beam.Create([permutation(V) for _ in xrange(N)])`. However, I was a little thrown off by the comment in [the documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#creating-a-pcollection), "The latter is primarily useful for testing and debugging purposes." Maybe a slight improvement is to perform the permutation in a `DoFn`.

I have one last idea. It sounds a bit stupid (and it may well be stupid), but hear me out on this one (humor my sleep-deprived self). [The documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-custom-io/#reading-from-a-new-source) points to an implementation of `CountingSource` (and, along with it, `ReadFromCountingSource`). Is there a benefit to using `ReadFromCountingSource(N)` over `beam.Create(range(N))`? If so, is the following (start of a) `Pipeline` reasonable:

```
(p | 'trial_count' >> ReadFromCountingSource(N)
   | 'permute_v' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda _, x: permutation(x), V)
   | ...)
```

Beam/Dataflow experts, what would you recommend?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load matrices from a `.mat` file into a `PCollection`, derive a `PTransform` wrapper around `scipy.io.loadmat` from `beam.Create`:

```
class LoadMat(beam.Create):

    def __init__(self, file_name, mdict=None, appendmat=True, **kwargs):
        mat_dict = scipy.io.loadmat(file_name, mdict, appendmat, **kwargs)
        super(LoadMat, self).__init__([mat_dict])
```

Call this transform as follows:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    matrices = (p
                | 'LoadMat' >> LoadMat(FileSystems.open(known_args.input))
                | ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me rephrase what I think you're asking, please correct me if I'm wrong:

You have a matrix `V` in a MATLAB file, which needs to be read in and then run through `N` trials of a simulation.

**EDIT: `FileBasedSource` cannot be used directly. I've corrected my explanation below.**

Apache Beam has built-in PTransforms for reading from many file formats, but not MATLAB files. You'll need to create your own source implementation and Read transform. There are many examples based on `FileBasedSource`, such as [`ReadFromTFRecord`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fd85372b377c78515a0fb4418353509532d8f841/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/tfrecordio.py#L181) and [`ReadFromAvro`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fd85372b377c78515a0fb4418353509532d8f841/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/avroio.py#L66).

The Beam documentation has tips on implementing new I/O transforms: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/authoring-overview/

Adding the logic for permutations will be simpler if it's decoupled from the source. If the number of trials `N` is static or known during pipeline construction, you can use [FlatMap](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=pardo#apache_beam.transforms.core.FlatMap) and normal Python code to return an iterable of each permutation. So you're logic would look more like:

```
(p | 'read' >> ReadFromMatlab(file_name)
   | 'permute_v' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: permutation(x, N))
   | ...)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think you've misunderstood. My conclusion was that `FileBasedSource` is **not** the correct answer to my problem. For one, you can't just do `FileBasedSource(file_name)`, right? You'd need to subclass `FileBasedSource`, since `read_records` (and maybe other stuff) is not defined for `FileBasedSource`. Furthermore, `FileBasedSource` seems intended for cases where you get a `PCollection` of text lines/JSON objects/something from the file, especially if that read could be parallelized, and none of that is true in my case (especially with `.mat` being a binary format). On permutation:

Comment: The basic challenge that I'm facing is that the Apache Beam/Dataflow model seems to be well-suited to taking a `PCollection` of `M` objects and transforming it to another `PCollection` of `M` objects, or perhaps grouping by key and reducing the number of output `PCollection` objects, not so much what I want to do: take a `PCollection` of `M` (in my case, 1) objects, and turn it into a `PCollection` of `M * N` objects. I guess your logic is fine for that, assuming the `permutation` call returns a list of `N` objects, like my implementation `[permutation(V) for _ in N]` in the original question.

Comment: @user1093967 Thanks for pointing out my original answer was incorrect with regards to using `FileBasedSource`. I've updated my answer to reflect that you'll need to subclass and create a read transform. For permutations, `FlatMap` can output many elements for a single input.

Comment: As I wrote in my question and initial comment on your answer, I believe that creating a new sourcing using the Source API is not the answer here. Prior to asking my question, I'd studied the code for `AvroSource` and other examples, and I revisited them over the past few days. I still don't see how it applies in this case. I'll add an answer with the solution I eventually came to yesterday, and you're welcome to see if that seems more reasonable given my use case.